# Optimise Stored Procedure Update and Select

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

The stored procedure I've created works, but is there a more efficient way of doing this? To be fair there is no performance hit for any of this nor does it need optimised but I'd like to know in the interest of doing things correctly.

Execution plan states `query 1: 17%`, `query 2: 67%`, `query 3: 16%`

```
DECLARE @CurrentVoucherID int;

SET @CurrentVoucherID  = 
    (
        SELECT TOP(1) IdGiftVoucherPhysicalCode 
        from GiftVoucherPhysicalCodes
        WHERE Activated = 0 and assigned = 0 and Value = 10
        ORDER BY IdGiftVoucherPhysicalCode
    );

UPDATE GiftVoucherPhysicalCodes
SET Activated = 1, Activated_at = GETDATE()
WHERE IdGiftVoucherPhysicalCode = @CurrentVoucherID;

SELECT * FROM GiftVoucherPhysicalCodes
WHERE IdGiftVoucherPhysicalCode = @CurrentVoucherID;
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this, would do it the same way...

Comment: Thanks, strikes me that the select is being run twice to return the same record though which kinda bugs me.

Comment: But the execution plan does not account for the index being in memory.   If IdGiftVoucherPhysicalCode is indexed that last where is a trivial index seek.

Comment: My concern with this would not be performance, but it is open to incorrect results if multiple processes are running at teh same time. If you get the value outside the update, there is no guarantee that something else is not going to change that between the parameter being set and teh update running. You would need to explicitly lock the table or put the check into the update statement itself. You can get into a data integrity mess with this technique.

Comment: @HLGEM this sproc is only called from a webapp where the requests are queued to avoid this issue, although to be fair that's maybe not the ideal approach.

Comment: @Blam, I had hoped something like this would be the case, if you'd like to turn that into an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I may not be understanding it correctly, but it looks like you are just running the update one record at a time?  Why not do it in bulk?

```
UPDATE GiftVoucherPhysicalCodes
SET Activated = 1, Activated_at = GETDATE()
WHERE Activated = 0 and assigned = 0 and Value = 10
```

Comment: I'm updating one specific record at a time, I need to get the next sequential available record that hasn't been activated.

Comment: So you aren't able to update all records that have not been activated, you have to do it sequentially?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it without variable

```
UPDATE GiftVoucherPhysicalCodes
SET Activated = 1, Activated_at = GETDATE()
WHERE IdGiftVoucherPhysicalCode = (SELECT TOP(1) IdGiftVoucherPhysicalCode 
                            from GiftVoucherPhysicalCodes
                            WHERE Activated = 0 and assigned = 0 and Value = 10
                            ORDER BY IdGiftVoucherPhysicalCode)

SELECT * FROM GiftVoucherPhysicalCodes
WHERE IdGiftVoucherPhysicalCode = (SELECT TOP(1) IdGiftVoucherPhysicalCode 
                            from GiftVoucherPhysicalCodes
                            WHERE Activated = 1 and assigned = 0 and Value = 10
                            ORDER BY IdGiftVoucherPhysicalCode)
```

Comment: In your suggestion the second select statement wouldn't return the desired record because you've already updated the record to set `activated` to `true`. You couldn't change it to activated either as it would still grab the incorrect record unless it was the first time the query had ever been run.